# spark & zeppelin problems with integration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I want to connect my locally installed zeppelin 0.10.0 to an also locally installed spark 3.2.0 (I tried the same procedure with spark2.3.0 and it worked.). But it looks like zeppelin itself has an internal spark which uses the internal one every time I try. I have gone through the setting for spark interpreters with no use.
I just want to know if there is anyway I can change the default internal spark that zeppelin uses and change it to a spark 3.2.0 I want to use.

I put the parameters of `SPARK_HOME` what it is said to be and `spark.master local[*]` receiving the following error:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Settings.usejavacp()Lscala/tools/nsc/settings/AbsSettings$AbsSetting;
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:833)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:741)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Settings.usejavacp()Lscala/tools/nsc/settings/AbsSettings$AbsSetting;
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala212Interpreter.open(SparkScala212Interpreter.scala:66)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:121)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    ... 8 more
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Settings.usejavacp()Lscala/tools/nsc/settings/AbsSettings$AbsSetting;
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:833)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:741)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Settings.usejavacp()Lscala/tools/nsc/settings/AbsSettings$AbsSetting;
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala212Interpreter.open(SparkScala212Interpreter.scala:66)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:121)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the same issue myself - you won't run `Spark 3.2.0` on `Zeppelin 0.10.0`. `Spark 3.1.2` works without any issues and Zeppelin has `Spark 2.4.5` included - this is a problem with a tool itself.

According to the ticket [ZEPPELIN-5565](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5565) version `0.10.0` DOES NOT support `Spark 3.2.0`. This should be fixed in `0.10.1` and `0.11.0` (info from mentioned ticket and I've also checked the Github repo).

Pull request that fixes this issue is much longer, but in `Zeppelin 0.10.0` there is this strategic line:

```java
public static final SparkVersion UNSUPPORTED_FUTURE_VERSION = SPARK_3_2_0;
```

Comment: Thank you, zeppelin `0.10.1` worked for me